# How can I solve my segmentation fault core dumped error?

Tags: c, posix

I'm trying to figure out why I keep getting segmentation fault core dumped as an error when I try to run my program. It happens after I run this part of my code:

```
 for(size_t i = 0; i< fLength;i++){
    splitPath = strtok(path1, ":");//spltting the string by coln
    while(splitPath!=NULL && (pathsFound == 0 || a_flag == 1)){
        // if no flag,
        // it'll only loop through once if path is found.
        // It'll loop through until all paths have been checked and
        // printed if there is a flag
        copy = strcpy(copy,"");
        copy = strcpy(copy,splitPath);
        strcat(copy, "/");
        strcat(copy, fileName[i]);
        if(file_exists(copy)){
         printf("\n%s\n",copy);
          pathsFound == 1;
        }
splitPath = strtok(NULL, ":");
    }
    if(pathsFound == 0){
      return 1;
    }
  }//end of for
```

and so from the research, I've been doing it could have something to do with my file_exist function which returns either true or false depending on whether or not a file exists. Apparently most common cases have to do with trying to access a file when you don't have permission? Either way Here is my file_exists function

```
bool file_exists(char* path) {
//int accessValue = access(path, F_OK);
// access returns -1 if it cannot access file and 0 otherwise
int check = 0;
  struct stat buffer;
    int exist = stat(path,&buffer);
    if(exist == 0)
        check = 1;
    else // -1
        check = 0;

if(check == 1){
    return true;
}else{
    return false;
}
}
```

So this is a function I'm creating as a library to include into my main.c file. I just googled how to check if a file exists and tried a couple of different programs. All had the same result. So maybe it's not even my file_exists function.

Can you guys please help me decipher what's going on? Just as a heads up, I'm new to C and this is the first program that I'm making!

EDIT#1:
this is the first part of my code

```
int a_flag = 0; //counter
int return_value = 0;
const char *fileName[argc]; //size related to amount of arguments
int fLength = 0;
int fileFound;
char* copy;
char *path1 = getenv("PATH"); //file path
char *splitPath;//spltting the string by coln
  int pathsFound = 0;//counting the amount of existing paths that have been found

 for (size_t i = 1; i < argc; i++){
    if (strcmp(argv[i], "-a") == 0){
      a_flag = 1;
    }else{
      if (argv[i][0] == '-'){
        printf("Invalid flag!\n");
        return 2;
      }else{
        fileName[fLength]=argv[i];
        fLength++;
      }
      // Either:
      // 1. We have an unknown flag
      // 2. We have a filename
    }
  }
printf("%d\n",fLength);
 

splitPath = strtok(path1, ":");
while(splitPath!=NULL){
printf("\n%s\n", splitPath);
splitPath = strtok(NULL, ":");
   }
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Hmm..., using `strcpy` and `strcat` without first controlling the available array size is a nice recipe to generate segfaults...

Comment: @Aviera00 : Why is this tagged _bash_? There is nothing bash-related in the question.

Comment: @Aviera00 : Where is the declaration for the variable `copy`?

Comment: @user1934428 I'm sorry I totally forgot. Just as a bit of context, this program is meant to be a copy of the "which" bash command. So I'm trying to get a path, split it by the ":" character and concatenate it with "/argument" which is the file name, and see if it exists, if it does, then I print it. It alo behaves differently on whether or not there is an -a flag.

Comment: @SergeBallesta Can you please elaborate? I just posted the first part of my code where I initialize all my variables. Any advice is appreciated

Comment: Try compiling with `-fsanitize=address -Og -g` flags and run it again; you will receive additional details at the segmentation fault that might give you the answer, or at least would be good clarification here (be sure to make clear what lines of your sample the stacktrace line numbers refer to)

Comment: Do you know how to run the program under a debugger, like `gdb program`? If not, learn it. It will save you countless weeks of head-scratching over your programming life.

Comment: So I found out my program fails when I try and strcopy(copy, splitPath)

Comment: You declared a pointer `copy`, but never allocate memory for it. Of course your `strcpy` will core dump! Did you maybe mean `strdup` here?